# CakePHP:: How to create Dropdown using Custom SQL query

Tags: cakephp

In UsersController:

```
$query = $this->User->query("SELECT name FROM Type");
$this->set('type',$query);
```

In view.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Type_id',array('options'=>$type));
```

This adds Admin,Type,1 and User, Type to dropdown.

I want to display only **`Admin and User`** in Dropdown.

**Type Table contains only Two Columns id and type**.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: what `$query` will give you here ?

Comment: $query contains result of "SELECT name FROM Type"

Comment: using json_encode,  [{"Type":{"name":"Admin"}},{"Type":{"name":"User"}}]

Comment: Is Type a table here? and is it associated with User Model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
$query = $this->User->query("SELECT id,name FROM Type");    
$query = Hash::combine($query, '{n}.Type.id', '{n}.Type.name');
$this->set('type',$query);
```

**OR**

You can also do the above thing if there is a association between the `User` and `Type` Models

i.e.

`$types = $this->User->Type->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'name')));`

and in view.ctp

`echo $this->Form->input('type_id',array('options'=>$types)); // here better to use type
_id instead of Type_id`

Comment: Glad it helped, Better if you set `$query` using some associations between users and types.

Answer (score 0):

Use the conventions

Try to avoid plain SQL.

You should use Model::find('list') and adapt it to your needs

[Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) is the documentation you need.